# Converting a jQuery plugin to work on any object, not just DOM objects

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I am using the [jQuery physics plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jphysics) for a pet project I am working on.

The plugin enables the moving of DOM objects in realistic ways using velocity, gravity, wind etc.

However I want to use the plugin to calculate where objects are to be placed inside a canvas element, not DOM object.

**How do I change the [plugin script](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.physics.0.3.js.txt) to work for ANY object with 'top' and 'left' properties rather than only working with DOM objects found with a jQuery selector?**

Currently the script functions look like this:

```
jQuery.fn.funname = function() {
    return this;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// line 172 jquery.physics.js
if (!params.position) this.position = new $.Vector(parseFloat($(this).css('left')),parseFloat($(this).css('top')));
```